# Magento template for each category/product

Tags: magento, templates, layout, categories, product

I need to change category and product view for each category/product, for change category list I have add into local.xml:

```
<layouts>
<CATEGORY_3> 
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <name>catalog/product/list-1.phtml</name>
       </action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_3>
</layouts>
```

but I don't know how to change layout from product of category_3, I try adding

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>catalog/product/view-1.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </action>
</reference>
```

inside  tag but nothing, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

First off, your second XML config block seems to be missing a `.phtml` extension inside `<template></template>`.

Second, your `action method="setTemplate"` is nested twice. Remove the first one

```
<reference name="product.info">
<!-- action method="setTemplate" REMOVED-->
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/product/view-1.phtml</template>
    </action>
<!-- /action REMOVED-->
</reference>
```

Also the template you're trying to call
Additionally, Please don't do this from local.xml. You **will** have caching issues. I guarantee it. This is probably one of the reasons why you're not seeing changes. We did a similar thing last month and it bit us in the arse.

Instead go to `Catalog > Manage Categories > (Click on/Select a Category) > Custom Design Tab` and then enter your XML layout changes at the `Custom Layout Update` box. This worked for us better and thus it might give you a better chance of success, too.

[image: Per-category custom layout updates]

Comment: While technically you can do that, I only recommended you best practice out of experience. Do what you want, I'm not the boss of you :) but if you do run into problems with this, you know the _correct_ solution (according to our team's experiences anyway).

Comment: thank you for this help, I want to do all via code because in this way the admin of this site can't edit the layout and create problem, only for this!

Comment: Alright! Also I put in a note _on my answer_ about your `<template></template>` tag (second one) missing the `.phtml` extension.

Comment: yes, this is an error while I write the question :)

Comment: Edited my answer again.. I noticed something, your <action> tags are called twice.